# how to add watermark to pdf(itext7.1.2 java)

Tags: java, itext7

It's the code I followed one sample.

the code i was modified a little.

```
public class MyEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
    PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
        page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDoc);

    DeviceRgb colorWatermark = new DeviceRgb(220,36,31);
    //Add watermark
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, page.getPageSize());
    canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT_COLOR, colorWatermark);
    canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, 60);
    try {
        canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT, PdfFontFactory.createFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H",true));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    canvas.showTextAligned(new Paragraph("CONFIDENTIAL"),
        298, 421, pdfDoc.getPageNumber(page),
        TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 45);
    pdfCanvas.release();
  }
}
```

when the code goto the line:`canvas.showTextAligned()`

It throws out an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.layout.property.UnitValue
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.getPropertyAsUnitValue(AbstractRenderer.java:405)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TextRenderer.layout(TextRenderer.java:196)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.layout(LineRenderer.java:327)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.layout(ParagraphRenderer.java:205)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.layout(BlockRenderer.java:219)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:287)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.CanvasRenderer.addChild(CanvasRenderer.java:89)
at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.createAndAddRendererSubTree(RootElement.java:377)
at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:106)
at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.showTextAligned(RootElement.java:364)
at com.schindler.zhangzhiwei.quote.action.MyEventHandler.handleEvent(MyEventHandler.java:56)
```

what happened? what is UnitValue? how to change it?

this is the main code:

```
try {

        writer = new PdfWriter(new File(openSaveDialog()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new MyEventHandler());
```

Comment: Which one is line 56 in your code?

Comment: it's `canvas.showTextAligned()`.some annotation i was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem finally.i give up the method of canvas. then, i transmitted the `document` parameter to the `MyEventHandler`. Use the following sentence:`document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World").setFixedPosition(298, 421, 100).setRotationAngle(45).setFontColor(colorWatermark).setFontSize(100));`

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.layout.property.UnitValue

This means that the *framework* you are using assumes that a certain value should be of class `UnitValue`, but turns out to be an `Integer`.

A bit of guessing here: you have code like

```
canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, 60);
```

The above will end up putting an `Integer` object into some "property map". Most likely, you are *not* using that API correctly.

Meaning: the answer boils down to you studying the API documents for the product you are using. You have to understand how to *correctly* setup these property parameters.

From looking at the [javadoc](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.3/com/itextpdf/layout/property/class-use/UnitValue.html) for UnitValue, it looks like this class is used to somehow represent positions. So I would start by looking at properties that deal with "positioning".

Comment: thank you! you have pointed out the real problem and i have solve the question.

Comment: I think it makes sense if you accept your self-answer (as soon as the system allows you to do so). If you want to, you can show your appreciation by upvoting my answer though ;-)

Comment: By the way, `Canvas` is indirectly derived from `ElementPropertyContainer`, and from there it inherits `setFontSize`. Instead of setting the property directly, one should use that method.